# TSQL set concatenating varchar during cursor

Tags: sql, t-sql, cursor

When debugging, @buildEvents gets filled the first time it enters the loop but then never gets concatenated the next time around.  Is this possible inside of a cursor?

```
OPEN @BusinessCursor;
FETCH NEXT FROM @BusinessCursor INTO  @BusinessName;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

set @buildEvents = @buildEvents + @BusinessName

FETCH NEXT FROM @BusinessCursor INTO   @BusinessName;
END

CLOSE @BusinessCursor;
DEALLOCATE @BusinessCursor;     


      select @buildEvents
      return
```

Any ideas on how to get @buildEvents concatenated with @BusinessName?  The data im passing through is html data for an email.

Comment: Any chance you have a NULL resetting your variable and what you are actually seeing is only the last value? Throw a PRINT @BusinessName inside your cursor and see what the output is

Comment: varchar(max) is the length.  buildEvents only gets filled the first time it enters the loop with the FIRST value and BusinessName gets filled with a different value everytime but never concats into buildEvents

Comment: Note that your `select` is outside the `while` loop, so you're only printing one row

Comment: Yes its outside of the loop because I want buiildEvents output/results after its already concatenated as one long string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not doing one of 2 things probably:

1. when you declare `@buildEvents` assign it an empty string:

   `declare @buildEvents varchar(max) = ''`
2. in your loop check for `null` in `@BusinessName`:

   `set @buildEvents = @buildEvents + ISNULL(@BusinessName, '')`

Comment: Thanks it was the ISNULL!

Comment: Is there a way I can get 2900000 characters into this varchar string?  I tried casting it but it didn't work..... set @buildEvents = cast(@buildEvents +  ISNULL(@BusinessName, '') as varchar(max))

Comment: @SlopTonio, you already said that the type of buildEvents  is varchar(max), then why are you casting again? What is the problem?

Comment: @SlopTonio, max indicates that the maximum storage size is 2^31-1 bytes (2 GB)

Comment: @SlopTonio, try `set @buildEvents = @buildEvents + CAST(ISNULL(@BusinessName, '') as varchar(max))` or declare @BusinessName as varchar(max)

Comment: Same result it got truncated at length 43,679.  I need to fit about 290000 characters

Comment: @SlopTonio, try `select len(@buildEvents)`           https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/499608/ssms-can-not-paste-more-than-43679-characters-from-a-column-in-grid-mode

Comment: When I check the length after concat, I get 203856.   But when I copy and paste the results I get 43679.   So it looks like my data is being pushed correctly, the results pane was deceiving.  Thank you so much for all the help!